# How to remove words in a visual selection

Tags: neovim

Suppose I have the following input as shown below. What I would like to do is to visually select lines 2 through 4 (shift + v) and then delete the word dog.

How can I do that? I know I can use something like `:s/dog//` on my selection, but I was wondering if there's a more straightforward way.

```
1 The quick brown dog
2 dog jumps
3 over the
4 lazy dog,
5 but it should be just a fox.
```

The final output should be (affected only by the visual selection on lines 2 through 4):

```
1 The quick brown dog
2  jumps
3 over the
4 lazy ,
5 but it should be just a fox.
```

Comment: Crosspost of https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/vdxqc1/how_to_remove_word_in_a_visual_selection/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the special `'<,'>` markers at the colon prompt to restrict the scope of the command to the visual selection. If you hit `:` while a visual selection is active, it should prepopulate those for you.  So what you type is `:s/dog//` but the actual command you are running is `:'<,'>s/dog//`.

I don't know what would be a "more straightforward" way? How are you going to tell the editor what word to delete without typing it?  I don't think four extra characters beyond the word itself is an egregious requirement.

Comment: If OP's workflow involves search for the word 'dog' first, then `:'<,'>s//` is enough

Comment: I see. I was thinking something like `:/dog/d` when in visual selection mode. I'm already using `:s/dog//`. Thanks for you reply.

Comment: `:/dog/d` will delete the next entire line (within the selection, if qualified with `'<,'>`) that contains the word `dog`, rather than just the word itself. Prepending `g` (`:g/dog/d`) will delete all such lines instead of just the next one. (`:g/dog/p` would print the lines out at the bottom of the screen instead of deleting them; this is the origin of the name of the "grep" command, with "re" for "regular expression").